# How to trigger a custom error from inside a Jinja template?

Tags: ansible, custom-errors, template, jinja

Though Ansible itself has [a way for triggering a custom error](http://docs.ansible.com/fail_module.html), I can not find anything similar for Jinja.

My current method uses a *syntax* error:

```
{%  if 'ansible_mounts' in hostvars[host] %}
# {{ host }} knows its mount-points
{% else %}
# {% error!! No ansible_mounts listed for host - fact-gathering must've failed %}
{% endif %}
```

but those are rendered poorly at run-time -- one needs to look inside the template-file and search for the error (the rendering does not even include the line-number!).

Is there a way to output a neat failure message from inside Jinja-template?

Comment: You should write a plugin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21778252/how-to-raise-an-exception-in-a-jinja2-macro

Comment: Дякую пану. Якщо пан переробить свій коментар на _відповідь_, я її "прийму".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer from the comment:

There is no easy way to accomplish this – only via custom plugin. For details see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21778252/how-to-raise-an-exception-in-a-jinja2-macro

Answer (score 5):

Ansible adds the [mandatory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#forcing-variables-to-be-defined) filter to Jinja, which can be used to do this:

```
{{ ('OK text' if condition_ok) | mandatory('Text of error message') }}
```

gives the failure:

```
fatal: [hostname]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Text of error message"}
```

(Replace `condition_ok` with the check that you need to make; `'OK text'` can be just `''` if nothing should be substituted.)

Comment: Didn't work for me, and looking at the [source](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/989eeb243fcf9236bd54d4df60c01f6db4e642a7/lib/ansible/plugins/filter/core.py#L290) it actually checks that the thing passed in is undefined, not just false-y.

Comment: Thanks worked great.
{% if "ssh-rsa" not in d %}{{ DUMMY_SSH_ERR_NOT_RSA | mandatory('ONLY ssh-rsa keys allowed') }}{% endif %}

Answer (score 2):

I have written a jinja2 extension-[jinja2_error](https://github.com/mumubin/jiaja2_error) to raise error.

Firstly,

```
pip install jinja2_error
```

If you use  it with ansible

```
ANSIBLE_JINJA2_EXTENSIONS=jinja2_error.ErrorExtension ansible-playbook site.yml -v
```

If you use it with jinja2 Environment

```
    from jinja2 import Environment

    from jinja2_error import jinja2_error

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        env = Environment(extensions=[jinja2_error.ErrorExtension])
        render_text = """
                {% if 1==1 %}
                  {% error "It's error" %}
                {% endif %}
                """
        template = env.from_string(render_text)
        result = template.render({"a": "b"})
```

If you want to know the details, please access

https://github.com/mumubin/jiaja2_error

Answer (score 1):

For those who looking for like mandatory filter but not using ansible

```
{%- if not param.columns %} 
{# use 'include' wrong way, so it raise a error #}
{% include "required 'params.columns' not found!" %}
{%- endif %}
```